# In which way can I use operational amplifiers to amplify XLR signals?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio

I'm asking myself, how I can use operational amplifiers to amplify XLR signals? Let's say my XLR input gives me GND (1) Signal+ (2) and Signal- (3).

Can I simply connect 3 and 2 to my operational amplifier and than take the output (4) from my operational amplifier, combine it with the GND (1) and connect it to a speaker?

Are there any circuit plans with operational amplifiers that show how to build a preamp? (XLR -> XLR or XLR -> Cinch)

Comment: It's not quite that simple, but there are plenty of circuits available on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More or less, but you shouldn't use a bare op amp as the gain is to high.  You should build a differential amplifier.  This is probably exactly what you need:

[image: XLR input stage]

From: http://www.colomar.com/Shavano/intro_opamp2.html

It's difficult to make one of these differential amplifiers into a variable gain amplifier, but you can always follow it with a single-ended amplifier with variable gain, or a variable attenuator (pot as an adjustable voltage divider) an amplifier with fixed gain.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I simply connect 3 and 2 to my operational amplifier and than take
>   the output (4) from my operational amplifier, combine it with the GND
>   (1) and connect it to a speaker?

No that won't work as well as you'd expect it to. Firstly an op-amp is not a power amp (OK some are but these are very much more specialist devices) and you might only be able to get 40mA out and into an 8 ohm speaker that's about 12 milliwatts - about 1/4 the volume of a 1 watt amplifier (which of course you can get from the usual semiconductor sources).

Secondly, an op-amp is more akin to a mathematical device whose precise behaviour is defined by a set of resistors placed around it. If you fed -Vin and +Vin from your XLR signal it just wouldn't work and you'd either here nothing coming out or, it would sound a mess of distortion.

As for circuit ideas for a pre-amp you'd need to define how big and how small the inputs are going to be (millivolt levels), what input impedance you are looking for (microphones need less than guitars for instance and keyboards barely care providing the input impedance is over 100 ohms). Output level required and the output impedance required (usually less than 100 ohms is fine). What power supplies you'd expect it to operate from and probably a few other things like noise levels and bandwidth.

Or, just tell us what you are trying to achieve in terms of inputs and outputs and maybe google a bit for ideas.

Comment: Hello, first of all thanks for taking the time to answer me.

I´m simply trying to get a xlr signal from a microphone, then amplify the given signal(control the amplifycation with a rotary knob) and feed it to my camera(600D) with a cinch plug. Beside the primary output for the camera there should also be a second output for monitoring the amplified sound with headphones.

I`m trying to build a similar device like the juicedlink preamps, because i think they are overpriced.